# Is it possible to scan for Bluetooth devices without the bluetoothd daemon running?

Tags: linux, drivers, bluetooth, kernel, c

I am working on an embedded system and I need to scan for Bluetooth devices. I want to do this with my own program, which I can do using the hci_get_route() and supporting hci functions from the BlueZ devel stuff. However, scanning only works while bluetoothd is running. Is there any possibility of doing this without needing bluetoothd running in the background?

**UPDATE:**

Per harrymc's answer, I was able to get Bluetooth scanning to work without bluetoothd or even systemd running. I did, however, need to load the following kernel modules (kernel 5.19):

```
hci_uart
btusb
```

As long as those modules loaded at boot, all I needed to do was run this: `hciconfig hci0 up` and I could then scan for Bluetooth devices. **I did not need to run hciattach.** My laptop uses an Intel Bluetooth adapter (lsusb reports vendor/product as 8087:0033).

Comment: Only if you emulate the functionality of the demon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post
[Linux command to connect to a Bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714625/linux-command-to-connect-to-a-bluetooth-device)
might be pertinent.

This unanswered post details using HCI as follows.

To setup the Bluetooth hardware:

```
sudo modprobe hci_uart
sudo modprobe btbcm
sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -
```

To scan devices :

```
sudo hcitool scan
```

However, this software failed to actually connect successfully to devices,
at least for the poster of that post.

Comment: This worked! I didn't have to use hciattach. As long as I loaded the hci_uart module, hciconfig -a showed the USB Bluetooth adapter already attached. I'll update the question with the details.

Comment: Note that I had to add -i hci0  like this sudo hcitool -i hci0 scan to make that command work